# How to navigate BlackBerry BrowserField2 in OS5

Tags: blackberry

I am using the new BrowserField2 in BlackBerry OS5 to display HTML content in my app. There are 3 options available for navigation through links in that content.

CURSOR navigation uses a block cursor and actually moves through the characters of the page. Not very useful for me.

POINTER navigation uses a mouse like pointer that you move around the screen and hover over elements. This could work but there is a bug however in that the browser field captures navigation and never lets go so this mode is effectively broken if you share a screen with any other managers. Once your focus enters the browser field you cannot move focus back out and into neighboring fields. RIM has acknowledged the bug but has no work around.

NONE which is for custom navigation but they offer no explanation as to how you would do this.

What I ideally want is to simply have trackpad movements move the focus through the links and highlight them. Then a click would activate the link. I assume I would select the NONE option above and implement my own focus navigation but I am not clear how this can be accomplished with the new APIs.

Is anyone familiar with the new browser2 component could give some guidance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually reverted back to the older browser1 (OS4) component because the navigation problems in browserField2 (OS5) were a deal breaker for me. Luckily the OS4 browser does everything I need in terms of functionality and it has the exact navigation behavior I need and there are no focus problems mixing it with other views.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaroudn to getting back the focus out of the BrowserField using the NAVIGATION_POINTER.

I found it in this thread:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BrowserField-2-Navigation-Mode/td-p/632172

"farahh" posted this:
I found out a hack..

with the navigation set to pointer mode, a click outside the browserfield manager invokes Manager.invokeAction(int). I used the getFieldWithFocus to verify which field has focus and then switch the focus to something else.

Cheers.
Nahuel

PD: i havent found out how to get the behaviour you want, i need that as well so if you got it working please let me know, its kinda urgent in my project =(